# Google Developers Console API page not loading

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

In my Google Developers Console I cannot open APIs Page. Its shows Failed to load error and if i enable any other API using through links like (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/#loadbalancingsetup) means it shows Server error. I tried to open the APIs page in different browsers and i have already waited 48 hours.!

Comment: I have the same issue as well. It happened after I tried to enable Google Cloud messaging.

Answer (score 6):

My name is Nikita and I'm a representative of Google Cloud Platform Support. It looks like you were affected by a transient issue affecting a limited number of projects. 
We thank you for your patience and apologize for any inconvenience it may caused.

For those encountering this again, please discard this being a browser issue (incognito without extensions) and feel free to report as a public issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=1162610) or, if you need to include any PII, as a private issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491375&template=1161233).

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. The old link doesn't work..it is redirecting to new console.

Comment: Today is end of 2018 and this issue is still not fixed. Shame on you google

Comment: Looks like this issue is still there. I created one Apps Script Project today and trying to open Credentials Page in Cloud Console, It is not opening.

Comment: I don't have this problem. After discarding this being a browser issue you can raise a public issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=1162610) or private issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491375&template=1161233)

Comment: @NikitaUchaev I am having the same problem now. I need this resolved urgently please, I am working on a mobile application use your geo APIs. Thanks!