# Can not Enable API in Google Developer Console

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to enable an api on my project to allow youtube videos to play on my website.

In the developers console, under API manager:

When clicking on the 'Overview', I am getting a 'Failed to load' message.

I am unable to enable the API that I need because of this.

I have searched and found nothing.

Comment: What's the version of the browser you're using? Operating system? There's a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27405582/4241842) question where the workaround was to use [this](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&pli=1#project:YOUR_PROJECT_ID:services) link, does it work for you?

Comment: Have you tried disabling your browser extensions?